# How does Particle Filters work?

Tags: monte-carlo, particle-filter, sequential-monte-carlo

I'm trying to figure out how particle filter works.
Assume that I have selected propability function called $a \sim Gauss(\mu, \sigma)$. We call it proposial (Gaussian) Distribution.

Then we have another function who corresonds to the real world variance and mean of the measurement. We call it $b \sim  \text{Lognormal}(\mu, \sigma)$ target distribution.

Assume that we have $N$ population of samples $x_0, x_1, x_2, x_2, \dots , x_N $ and we want to determine which one is the most correct sample.

As I understand about the particle filter, we need compute so called weights for every $x_N$.

My idea is that we need to have the density function of both Gaussian distribution and Lognormal distribution.

$$f_{gauss}(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2}$$
$$f_{loggnormal}(x) = \frac{1}{x\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(\ln(x)-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

Then to find the weights $w$, then we need to divide

$$w_i = \frac{f_{loggnormal}(x_i)}{f_{gauss}(x_i)}, i = 0, 1, 2, 3, \dots , N$$

Then what? What should I do next to find out what's the most correct $x$ value are?
What if the target distribution changes over time?

**Edit:**

I have looked into this `.pdf` file about `Importance Sampling and Particle Filters` and Particle Filters makes no sense to me now.
[http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~16831-f14/notes/F14/16831_lecture04_josephba.pdf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E16831-f14/notes/F14/16831_lecture04_josephba.pdf)

Why?
Because you need to first know how the propability density of your current samplig measurement looks like first, before you selecting a target distribution. And if the propability density of your current sampling measurement, then you need to change the target distribution as well.

Also, what's the point of having a particle filter, if you already know the distribution of your current sampling measurement?

Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The general context and problem structure for which you have outlined particle filtering to be a solution is new to me.  As I understand from the probabilistic graphical model literature, particle filtering is normally used in context of linear dynamical systems, or sequential models, examples of which include hidden Markov models and Kalman filters. And that they rely on weighted resampling ideas for simulation-based Bayesian inference.

Comment: For this reason I understand that they are implemented when i) there is a sequential model with latent variables ii) there is an intractable posterior over latent variables for which a sample-based approximation is sought iii) recursive, online time and measurement updates are needed. I am no simulation expert, but given that there doesn’t seem to be an explicit temporal connotation to what you have specified, nor any of the other properties, please may you clarify what it is about the problem you have specified which you think admits particle filtering as a solution?

Comment: @microhaus Well, I'm going to do distance measuring and then I need some knowledge about PF. I think I understand now PF. First, we don't know the target densitiy function, but we want to create that. That's the goal with PF. To create that densitiy function, one must first use Monte Carlo Simulation to create the discrete propability function $q(x)$ and we are going to shape the propotional densitiy function $N(x, \mu, \sigma)$ by using weights. We get those weights from $w_i = \frac{q(x)}{N(x, \mu, \sigma)}$. So when we got our weights, then we have our densitiy function $w_i N(mu, sigma)$